# Is it possible to read a JSON sub-object directly as a JSON DOM object or Data or some other generic format?

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

Is there a JSON DOM that can read any JSON, regardless of type, and store it into something like a Dictionary hierarchy?

Consider this JSON and code...

```
var jsonData = """
    {
        "type":"ListWrapper",
        "objectData": {
            "label":"SuperItems",
            "items":[
                {
                    "value":"First"
                },
                {
                    "value":"Second"
                },
                {
                    "value":"Third"
                },
                {
                    "value":"Fourth"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    """.data(using:.utf8)!
```

Here's the first part of what we're trying to do. (Note: This doesn't actually work.)

```
class TestObject : Codable {
    var name:String?
    var childObject:Data? // <-- This is the 'wishful' part
}

do{
    let testObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(TestObject.self, from:jsonData)
    processTestObject(testObject)
}
catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Now somewhere else in the application, we have this defined (Note it matches the object stored in 'objectData' above) and we're trying to do this...

```
class ListWrapper : Codable {
    var label:String?
    var items:[ListItem]?
}

class ListItem : Codable {
    var value:String?
}

do{
    switch testObject.type{

        case "ListWrapper":
            var listWrapper = try JSONDecoder().decode(ListWrapper.self, from:testObject.objectData)
            processList(listWrapper)

        case "Foo":
            var listWrapper = try JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from:testObject.objectData)
            processFoo(foo)
    }
}
catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

> Note: Yes, we know we can encode the JSON in 'objectData' and store it as a string, but we're trying to leave the JSON as-is.

One approach would be to write a custom deserializer for `TestObject` but we'd have to tell it all the possible types we're looking for. We can do that, but I was hoping to make it a 'dumb' object that just stores the JSON as data or something similar.  So is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not, but you could make the type of `items` generic. That's the usual *swifty* way to handle different types.

Comment: Items is just an arbitrary object.  The point is who's deserializing the initial JSON has no knowledge of what type is stored in `objectData`, but storing it as a string is inherently unsafe, hence this question.

Comment: The goal of `Codable` is that you **do** know the type. Even with plain `JSONSerialization` – which `Codable` is based on – you must have an idea what you are going to decode.

Comment: We do know, just not at the time of decoding the initial object.  Think about it a different way... we're trying to make a JSON payload as a child property of a different object.  It's a 'box'... you hand the box to someone else. You don't have to look in the box.  Someone else *will* know, as my example above shows, but the initial decoder I simply want to re-encode that child object as data and pass it along.

Comment: Then deserialize the object and reencode the child object with `JSONSerialization`. `Codable` doesn't support `Any`

Comment: But deserialize the object into what type?  That's my entire question!  The concrete type isn't known at that point, nor can it be.  That's why I said I could simply do it as a string.  Yes, a string that *happens* to hold JSON, but TestObject doesn't need to know, or care, what's in the strong.  I was just trying to avoid doing it as a string as that means we would have to modify the JSON.  But if you know of a 'generic' (not as in generics, but as in a generic JSON DOM object model) we could deserialize arbitrary JSON into, that would be perfect.  Make sense?

Comment: The root object seems to be `[String:Any]` and `JSONSerialization` can serialize *Any* (child) object. In the case of an unknown root object there are only two collection types, array and dictionary.

Comment: Maybe something like [AnyCodable](https://github.com/Flight-School/AnyCodable) would help