# Can you decode a child JSON object into its string representation instead of a concrete type?

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

Ok, asking a question that is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59794057/168179) that I posted the other day. The difference here is I'm wondering if a sub-object's json can be read in as an escaped string of JSON itself rather than being decoded.

Consider this json...

```json
{
    "value" : "SomeValue",
    "child" : {
        "prop1" : "Value1",
        "prop2" : "Value2"
    }
}
```

You can decode that into these classes without issue...

```swift
class Wrapper : Codable {
    let value : String
    let child : ChildObject
}

class ChildObject : Codable {
    let prop1 : String
    let prop2 : String
}
```

What I'm wondering is if it's possible to write a custom decoder that will let me decode it into this...

```swift
class Wrapper : Codable {
    let value : String
    let child : String  <-- Note: String
}
```

...and have Wrapper.child equal this...

```swift
// Wrapper.child holds a string containing the escaped, raw JSON
Wrapper.child == "{\"prop1\":\"Value1\",\"prop2\":\"Value2\"}"
```

The only solution I have found so far is to explicitly decode into something like `AnyCodable` (on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Flight-School/AnyCodable)) which is a glorified anonymous-codable implementation, then re-serialize it back to JSON before assigning it to the actual property in the initializer.  Seems a bit overkill, but it does work.

```swift
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    // Get the container for the CodingKeys
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    // Set 'value' directly as a string
    value = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .value)

    // For 'child', Decode to an anonymous codable type,
    // Re-serialize that codable type back to JSON data
    // Convert that JSON data into a string, using that to set 'child'

    // decode an type-erased Codable object
    let anyCodable = try container.decode(AnyCodable.self, forKey: .child)

    // Reencode it back to JSON
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let childJsonData = try encoder.encode(anyCodable)

    // Set that JSON on the object's string property
    child = String(data:childJsonData, encoding:.utf8)!
}
```

It just feels 'smelly' to me to decode, just to re-encode it again.  Hoping there's a way to do this without that extra step.

Comment: The solution *smells* as unconventional as your request . You have to reincode the stuff. There is no other way with `Codable`

Comment: i do agree with @vadian

Comment: The issue is at the place where the decoding is done, there’s no way to know what the concrete types are. It is for all intents and purposes just a bucket that is going to be handed somewhere else. I originally was working with the backend team seeing if they could encode it as a string there, but they said it would break other systems, so I’m attempting to find an alternative.

Comment: Tell the backend team to send a key `type` along with the dictionary to be able to identify the concrete type. It's pretty bad practice to send unpredictable JSON.

Comment: They already do. The problem is those concrete types are defined in completely separate modules and there isn't a way to pass them in to the decoder.  Believe me, I know it's not optimal, but think of it like sending it over HTTP.  It doesn't know the concrete types. The receiver does. Same here. Where this is first decoded isn't the use-site. This is just delivering it to there.  That part *does* know the concrete types, and it will be decoded there.  Think of it like UPS.  They don't know or even care there's a shirt or a drone in the box. They just get the box where it's going.

Comment: To be clear, yes I know about UserData and such on the decoder.  I'm saying I don't control, nor have access to when this is decoded.  Only thing I have access to is the decodable initializer in this wrapper object which at some point in the future, it's handed off to the other part of the app that knows 'what's in the box'.  So think of this more as an arbitrary 'Data' payload that only the receiver knows what to do with it. Could be a string, could be a number, could be an object. It's not typed on the wrapper. It's 'Any'. I want to change it to String or Data.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an alternative solutions and this one below is an alternative one.

**Implement a CustomStringConvertible on ChildObject type.**

```
class ChildObject : Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let prop1 : String
    let prop2 : String

    var description: String {
        return "\(prop1) --- \(prop2)"
    }
}
```

and then call a *description* getter

```
child = childJsonData.description
```